# body onload does not trigger javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I attempt to get get a function triggered when a html page loads. To achieve this I am using body onload. It seems to me that the function isnt triggered. I have included thte jQuery Libraries in the head part of the page and checked that they really are located where they are supposed to. The script is calling a php file that checks a vaule in my database every second. It is supposed to return a status(response) to the html page.

Here is the html onload code:

```
<body onload="setInterval(check_search_status, 1000)" >
```

At the very bottom of my page, right before the body Close tag I have the function itself defined as a javasscript. As you can see I am trying to pass an id parameter to the checksearchstatus.php page by using a session variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function check_search_status(){
            $jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://internetsolutions.no/checksearchstatus.php',
                data: {
                    id: '{$_SESSION['owner']}';
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.status == 0){
                        window.location='http://internetsolutions.no/findings.php';
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: `id: '<?php echo $_SESSION["owner"]; ?>';`.

Comment: The console says 'Redirect was blocked for CORS-request'. Not sure what this means

Comment: Why poll to perform what is essentially a one-off task? It's not as if anything changes from poll to poll - the data is always the same.

Comment: The "CORS-request" error is because you are trying to make a cross domain ajax request, which is blocked by the browser.

Comment: The request I am doing is within the same domain. Any idea how to re-write the request so this error is avoided? What can be done?

Comment: I downloaded the .js files locally to my server. That resolved the CORS error Message issue

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
$jQuery.ajax({
```

to just

```
$.ajax({
```

Comment: How do you know that $jQuery !== $ in OP's case?

Comment: @dfsq I don't, assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function in `$(document).ready()` instead. Your codes contain syntax errors. Change `$jQuery.ajax` to `$.ajax` and  `id: '{$_SESSION['owner']}';` to `id: '<?=$_SESSION["owner"]?>'`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    check_search_status();
});
function check_search_status(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://internetsolutions.no/checksearchstatus.php',
        data: {
            id: '<?=$_SESSION["owner"]?>'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if(response.status == 0){
                window.location='http://internetsolutions.no/findings.php';
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `<script> var $111 = jQuery.noConflict();</script>

   <script type="text/javascript">

      function check_search_status(){
       $111.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://internetsolutions.no/checksearchstatus.php',
        data: {
         id: '135'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
         if(response.status == 0){
          window.location='http://internetsolutions.no/findings.php';
         }
        }
       });
      }

      $111(document).ready(function(){
       check_search_status();
      });
  </script>`

Comment: Sorry about the bad formating, but this is how the code looks now. Still not working. No error messages from this script in the console

Comment: Change `if(response.status == 0)` to `if(response.status == 1)`

Comment: The thing is that the value 0 is fetched from a database. Changing it to 1 will break the Logic in the Application. There are some errors thrown by other jquery scripts in the console, can this be the reason? Sorry, quite New to jQuery

Comment: jQuery execution is terminated by exception if occurred in same file!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues I see here, aside from ones others have pointed out.

1. You are mixing JS and PHP. Example:  `id: '{$_SESSION['owner']}';`. This can't be done since PHP runs server side, and JS runs client side (in browser). You
2. I think your onload event should be written: `setInterval(function() {check_search_status();}, 1000);`

Comment: Sorry but `id: '{$_SESSION['owner']}'` is possible. What we see here is a snippet from a server-side (PHP) script, not the eventually served page source.

Comment: And `setInterval(check_search_status, 1000)` is valid. A function can be specified by name. The anonymous function wrapper is not required.